# make element take up the space of a block, but render as inline

Tags: css

Here is an example of what I'm working with. http://jsfiddle.net/5J4PE/

I want the red and greed boxes to show up wrapped tightly around the text (like it is when using inline-block).

However, I want it to take up the space like when using block, such that the boxes appear stacked instead of in a line.

I don't want them to be the same width, so I don't want to use table-cell or any of the table displays.

I could just add a `<br/>` between the elements, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a span around the text & then set bg Color in css

```
<div><span class="red">hello</span></div>
```

then additionally you may use whatever styles on the outer divs.

Comment: To be honest, this is probably the preferred option to acheive things the way you've described, but that would require a change in your markup (then again, so would adding <br>s, and this is definitely the better than that). My line-feed/after hack may or may not work, but I'd say you'd be best off just changing your markup to have a span inside a div.

Answer (score 2):

It's just as nasty as `<br />` tags, but `float: left; clear: left;` on all elements would get you the effect you want. Pick your poison?

Obviously you'd lose some of the layout flow with the floats, so you'd need to adjust your parent to account for that.

Comment: Was just about to suggest this, as it's really about the only way to do it. +1

Comment: +1 for something that works.  I'm not going to use it because I don't want to change to float

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `before:` or `after:` pseudo-classes? These allow you to add content before or after a block, using CSS.

eg `<span>Hello</span>` styled with `span:after {content:" world";}` will produce `Hello world` in the browser.

If you specify a line-feed, it should put a blank line at the end of your block. Note: You'll need to specify it using the unicode value of the line-feed character.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1, interesting.   I'm not going to use it, but I'm glad to know of this.